# Is it possible to display a userform and executes a code bellow the .show method?

Tags: vba, vb6

I want to display Userform2 from Userform1 then **continue** executing some code in Userform1 **WITHOUT** unloading Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
 UserForm2.Show
 x = 1
 MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: any reason you can't have `UserForm2.Show` *after* "some code" runs? Does `UserForm2` have to be modal or it can be shown modeless?

Comment: Sorry- I meant without WITHOUT unloading Userform2

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that's what you want, but this would do what you describe:

```
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
```

Note that `UserForm2` isn't modal anymore, which means the user can click outside the form, and even end up hiding it behind `UserForm1`.

Modal forms return execution to the caller when they're hidden/closed or destroyed, modeless forms return execution to the caller immediately (`Initialize` and `Activate` handlers will run first though).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean without unloading `Userform2`...

`Userform1` will wait for `Userform2` to finish...  however you can do something like this:

**Userform1:**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 UserForm2.Show

End Sub

Sub uf1msgbox()

 X = 1
 MsgBox X

End Sub
```

**Userform2:**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.uf1msgbox
End Sub
```